# Onsen-UI Swipe Navigation

Tags: onsen-ui

I'm trying to figure out how to implement the "android" feel on Onsen-UI by using the 'swipe' navigation.

I tried implementing idangerous swiper, but not having much luck.  My idea is to combine:

http://codepen.io/negibouze/pen/jEvOYz

```
enter code here
```

http://codepen.io/negibouze/pen/wBLeyp

```
enter code here
```

When you swipe, the tabs change but has that swipe animation/effect.  I also would love it if each tab/swipe was a different html and not one index file.

Any ideas or help?

Answer (score 5):

Great question. There are two different approaches:

1. As it's done in your second example, using tabbar and gesture detector. Onsen 2.0 has a `slide` animation for tabbar, so you just need to add `<ons-tabbar animation="slide" ... >`. Onsen 2.0 is still in alpha version but it will be released in the upcoming weeks. The drawback of this approach is that the slide animation starts after the swipe action is completed.

You basically add your `ons-tabbar` element and then configure the gesture detector as follows:

```
ons.ready(function() {
  // Create a GestureDetector instance over your tabbar
  // The argument is the actual HTMLElement of tabbar, you can also do document.getElementById(...)
  var gd = ons.GestureDetector(myTabbar._element[0]); 

  gd.on('swipe', function(event) {
    var index = myTabbar.getActiveTabIndex();
    if (event.gesture.direction === 'left') {
      if (index < 3) {
        myTabbar.setActiveTab(++index);
      }
    } else if (event.gesture.direction === 'right') {
      if (index > 0) {
        myTabbar.setActiveTab(--index);
      }
    }
  })
});
```

Working here: https://jsfiddle.net/frankdiox/o25novtu/1/

2. Combining `ons-tabbar` and `ons-carousel` elements. The drawback of this approach is that `ons-carousel-item` cannot get a template or separated file (check the comments to find another workaround to this).

`ons-tab` requires a `page` attribute and you cannot leave it blank without errors in the console, but we can use `ons-tabbar`'s style instead of the actual component: http://onsen.io/reference/css.html#tab-bar

We combine it now with a fullscreen carousel like the one you mentioned and add the next CSS to make the page content respect our tabbar so it does not fall over or behind it:

```
ons-carousel[fullscreen] {
  bottom: 44px;
}
```

Next step, we link every tab with its corresponding carousel item:

```
<div class="tab-bar" id="myTabbar">
  <label class="tab-bar__item" onclick="carousel.setActiveCarouselItemIndex(0)">
    ...
  </label>

  <label class="tab-bar__item" onclick="carousel.setActiveCarouselItemIndex(1)">
    ...
  </label>

  <label class="tab-bar__item" onclick="carousel.setActiveCarouselItemIndex(2)">
    ...
</div>
```

And so on. This will make that when we click on a tab the carousel changes automatically. Now we need to do the opposite connection: update the checked tab when we swipe the carousel. The tabbar is basically a set of radio buttons, so we just need to get the one we want in the carousel's `postchange` event and check it:

```
ons.ready(function(){
  carousel.on('postchange', function(event){
    document.getElementById('myTabbar').children[event.activeIndex].children[0].checked = true; 
  });
});
```

You can now change the content of every `carousel-item-index` and insert an `ons-page` with anything you want.

Working here: http://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/EVpNVg

We may add a feature to make this easier in upcoming versions of OnsenUI.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sweet!  Thank you so much!  Is there a way to dynamically load external html files within each ons-page/carousel item?

Comment: @MarkB Not directly, but as usual there is a trick. You can put an `<ons-navigator page="myPage.html"></ons-navigator>` inside `<ons-carousel-item>`. Then put your content in a template `myPage.html` (I modified the Codepen example). Of course, these are all workarounds and are not the most efficient way to do it. I'm thinking in implementing something related to this for Onsen 2.0. By the way, please accept this answer if you consider it valid.

Comment: Yeah, the main effect I'm going for is this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brentvatne/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/master/demo.gif

With each "page/tab" having separate html from Onsen, just because I have several controllers to load for certain pages and it'd make it cleaner.